# Azure VM outbound HTTP is unreliable

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, httpconnection

I have setup and Azure VM and installed a monitoring service that reaches out to various endpoints to verify a 200 response.  The service is set to cycle through about 8 URL endpoints every 5 minutes or so.

We have run this service from multiple other servers outside of Azure, including virtual machines that are cheap, low end offerings.

While this machine is running on the lowest A0, it isn't doing anything else other than to run this service and call out to the various endpoints.

We are getting intermittent periods where one of the calls out of the list will fail for different periods that span 10-40 minutes at random periods several times a day.

The site or sites that fail are totally random and there is no down time from other monitor locations.  We are sure that the connection problem is between Azure and the endpoints outside of Azure.  There is no problem from anywhere outside of Azure.

I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this issue.  It concerns me because we will be adding more services to Azure soon that use outside HTTP calls for credit card authorization and other API's.

Is this a known issue where outbound calls just don't function reliably at periods, or am I missing something in the setup or security settings?

Obviously, if the call makes it out and the response doesn't make it back, that is even worse as credit card charges would end up being pushed and the application would not register the proper response.

Anyone with some experience or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to say offtopic. This isn't programming, this is server debugging. Try serverfault, maybe.

Comment: I hear you... but it isn't really a "server" issue, but applies more broadly to Azure platform, configuration and programming.  Frequently with these issues is a service or application configuration that is needed to address this.  I won't be surprised if developers recommend a retry policy in code to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that very disturbing and hard to believe since, among a lot of other stuff, I run a service like that too... In my case I reach out to several (today, about 70) external addresses on both IPV4 and IPV6. I don't run A0s, and most of my machines are A3. I'll start a A0 to test it... if anything turns out `<terminator>`i'll be back`</terminator>` to report...

I know that there are several limitations regarding network traffic but i don't think you can reach them the way you're reporting...

My suggestion is to report that problem directly to MS via support ticket... most likely the problem is on the other side...

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have heard that there is quite a disparity in different deployments of VM's, but I don't know why traffic would be inconsistent outbound like this.

I'd agree that the problem is on the other end, except that other monitors off Azure don't ever see these down blips.

Comment: I turned the service back on.  It's been about 50 hours without an issue. Based on your advice, I'm going to say that there was either some issue with the initial stand up of the server that eventually was sorted out behind the scenes or there was a coincidental issue that just happened to occur on the new server.  I appreciate the answer and knowing that others aren't having issues helps with confidence.

Comment: For those following this... I have had this service running now for a couple weeks with no repeat of the issue.