# Outbound HTTP calls occasionally being blocked on Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, httpconnection

EDIT: 3/16/17

Today we tried creating a new VM in the same private network and resource group (using the same network protection group as well), and ran the test, it worked perfectly. It makes no sense.

using PSping to diagnose this (using port 443 and 8001 to test) we can see the dropped traffic there as well, so it's not the application.  The same tests on the other test Azure VM work flawlessly. So it seems it is this particular VM, I just don't understand why, since nothing has changed. We also see dropped traffic to other random sites over 443 (ping and http are flawless).

We've tried rebooting and redeploying with no luck

Original:

Our Azure VM is experiencing random failures in creating connections to several 3rd party systems. occurring in a seemingly random fashion. (every 5-10 min or so an http call will fail)

Since Monday morning, we are seeing web service (http) calls made from the Azure VM fail in a seemingly random fashion- We are getting error messages suggesting the endpoint host is simply not responding. We have engaged both 3rd parties and it appears that these http calls are not reaching their servers at all. Everything was working fine up until Monday, and no changes have been made to the system.

We think the Azure VM (or Azure Networking Limits) are causing the problem because:

1. We created and deployed the same “test” program on both the Azure VM and an on-prem test VM with the same specs, and the program works fine using our on premise VM. 
   a. This program simply makes information request calls- a single one to each 3rd party system; the program is run every minute. Thus, both servers (Azure VM and On-prem VM) are repeating identical calls on the same schedule.
   b. On the test server, the success rate is 100%- we have seen no errors, even when I bumped it up to try every 10 seconds).
   c. On the production server, we see frequent errors connecting to both systems.

   2. In looking at the IIS logs from the 3rd Parties, We see blank spots when we see failed http calls In any event, no suspicious activity seems to be showing up in their case and their logs only show the successful calls.

We show only 10-20 TCP connections on the server, so we are not close to hitting the Azure 500k TCP connection limit.

Pings and tests to any site on the internet from the Azure VM seem to work fine, so network connectivity seems fine.

Are we hitting some other kind of limit on the Azure system, that could be causing these random errors?

I noticed this person had a similar issue but no resolution was found.([Azure VM outbound HTTP is unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296090/azure-vm-outbound-http-is-unreliable))

Comment: Hi, what is your VM size?

Comment: DS11(2 Core 14GB RAM, I also moved to DS3 (4 core 14GB RAM, but it didn't help) Thanks for the reply...we are pulling our hair out.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, I don't think Azure will limit this. If possible, you could open a ticket for Microsoft.

Comment: Are you able to do a route trace to see where the call to the 3rd party server is failing?

Comment: I added some comments above about the testing we did today, but still no luck.